# Installing django-cms on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip, django-cms

I've been trying to install django-cms into a virtual environment on Ubuntu. I've exactly followed the installation instructions in the docs (http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/support-3.0.x/introduction/install_from_scratch.html) but I keep getting an error after the following command.

```
djangocms -p . mysite
```

Error:

```
Path '.' already exists and is not empty, please choose a different one
If you want to use this path anyway use the -s flag to skip this check.
```

What does this mean and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the command a non-existing path as an argument in which it will create the project.

For example `djangocms -p mysite mysite`

Comment: Where does this path lead to? The 'Home' folder?

Comment: In this example it's "current directory" + "mysite/", you can also give a full path like ``djangocms -p /home/user/parentdir/``

Note you can completely leave out the ``-p`` flag and simply do ``djangocms mysite`` which will create the project in a directory named ``mysite`` under the current directory. See ``djangocms --help``